# Multiply Columns of two different dataframes

Tags: r

How to efficiently multiply columns of two different data frames with same number of rows but different number of columns. 
I have two data sets Volumes and prices and I want to multiply each volume column by each price column such that the resulting data frame would have nXm columns (n is `ncols` in first data frame and m is `ncols` in second data frame).

```
set.seed(159) # for reproducibility
volumes <- as.data.frame(cbind(Year = 2000:2004, 
                               matrix(round(runif(25, 50, 100), 0), 
                                      nrow = 5, ncol = 5)))
names(volumes) <- c("Year", paste(rep("V", 5), seq(1:5), sep = ""))
volumes
  Year V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 2000 56 52 88 81 52
2 2001 81 56 90 76 69
3 2002 81 92 69 93 69
4 2003 56 68 77 80 72
5 2004 51 58 62 53 62

set.seed(159)
prices <-   as.data.frame(cbind(Year = 2000:2004, 
                                matrix(round(runif(20, 5, 15), 0), 
                                       nrow = 5, ncol = 2)))
names(prices) <-  c("Year", paste(rep("P", 2), seq(1:2), sep = ""))
prices
  Year P1 P2
1 2000  6  5
2 2001 11  6
3 2002 11 13
4 2003  6  9
5 2004  5  7
```

Comment: Are the `Year` values always going to be the same? That is, can we just multiply one column by another, or do we need to match rows up by `Year` first?

Comment: For my current problem I have them same but it will be a good to know how to  match up and then multiply for future robustness in case they are not same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach. It's not the most efficient one but gets the job done:

```
result <- c()
for(i in names(volumes)) {
  for(j in names(prices)) {
    result <- c(result, volumes[i] * prices[j])
  }
}

# outcome of every combination as you want (m * n columns)
result_df <- as.data.frame(result)

# resulting column names are a bit messy but you can rename easily
# names(result_df) <- # your list of m * n names
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close, but needs modification to keep `Years` intact and get rid of original columns

Answer (score 0):

```
prices <- structure(list(Year = c(2001, 2003, 2002, 2000, 2004), P1 = c(15, 
8, 13, 12, 7), P2 = c(7, 10, 8, 14, 10)), row.names = c(2L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 5L), class = "data.frame")

volumes <- structure(list(Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004), V1 = c(76, 
78, 55, 74, 80), V2 = c(61, 80, 77, 68, 65), V3 = c(56, 52, 91, 
69, 90), V4 = c(50, 59, 51, 66, 58), V5 = c(75, 57, 57, 80, 59
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

We can do this in two steps using `lapply` and `purrr::reduce`.

First, we use `lapply` to loop through each column of `prices` and multiply `volumes` by that. `lapply` returns a list, with the output of each operation as a list item.

```
volumes_mult <- lapply(prices[,-1], function(p) {
    cbind(Year = volumes$Year, volumes[,-1] * p)
})
```

We then use `reduce` to apply a `*_join` operation to each item in the list. I recommend using `purrr::reduce` rather than base R `Reduce` because it makes it easier to supply additional arguments to `*_join` (we need the `by=` argument to properly join the tables). You can also customize the `suffix=` argument to choose how identical rows from different tables will be renamed:

```
purrr::reduce(volumes_mult, dplyr::full_join, by='Year', suffix = paste0('_', names(x)))

  Year V1_P1 V2_P1 V3_P1 V4_P1 V5_P1 V1_P2 V2_P2 V3_P2 V4_P2 V5_P2
1 2000  1140   915   840   750  1125   532   427   392   350   525
2 2001   624   640   416   472   456   780   800   520   590   570
3 2002   715  1001  1183   663   741   440   616   728   408   456
4 2003   888   816   828   792   960  1036   952   966   924  1120
5 2004   560   455   630   406   413   800   650   900   580   590
```

Comment: @AshishSinghal That wasn't clear from your initial question, but I see you've clarified it now. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for digging up this old thread. I just had the same problem and created this solution, which (in my real-life use case) is faster by a factor of 300 comapred to the lapply + reduce option:

```
library(tidyverse)
names_loop <- expand_grid(volumes_names = names(volumes)[-1],
                          prices_names  = names(prices)[-1])

left_join(volumes, prices, by = "Year") |> 
  add_column(map2_dfc(.x = names_loop[1],
                      .y = names_loop[2],
                      .f = ~volumes[.x] * prices[.y]) |> 
               rename_with(.cols = everything(),
                           .fn   = ~paste0(names_loop$volumes_names, "_", names_loop$prices_names)))

  Year V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 P1 P2 V1_P1 V1_P2 V2_P1 V2_P2 V3_P1 V3_P2 V4_P1 V4_P2 V5_P1 V5_P2
1 2000 56 52 88 81 52  6  5   336   280   312   260   528   440   486   405   312   260
2 2001 81 56 90 76 69 11  6   891   486   616   336   990   540   836   456   759   414
3 2002 81 92 69 93 69 11 13   891  1053  1012  1196   759   897  1023  1209   759   897
4 2003 56 68 77 80 72  6  9   336   504   408   612   462   693   480   720   432   648
5 2004 51 58 62 53 62  5  7   255   357   290   406   310   434   265   371   310   434
```